# 1062 Duplicate entry 'General' - skip the insert if there is already a category with same name

Tags: php, laravel

I have a migration post_categories like this:

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('post_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            
            $table->foreignId('post_id')
            ->nullable()
            ->constrained('posts');

            $table->unsignedSmallInteger('category_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('category_name')->nullable();
}
```

And in a Laravel nova Resource in the fields method there is some code that stores on the above table some categories that are being returned from the API request:

```
public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        $postInformation = (new postInformation)->handle(['field' => 'slug', 'value' => $this->slug]);
        $postId =  $postInformation['id'];

        try{
            DB::table('post_categories')->insert(
                array_map(fn ($category) => [
                    'post_id' => $postId,
                    'category_id' => $category['id'],
                    'category_name' => $category['name']['en_gb'],
                ], $postInformation['categories']['data'])
            );
        } 
        
}
```

And it works, however I'm getting this error:

```
exception: "Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException"
file: "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php"
line: 742
message: "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'General'
```

Do you know how to, if there are already a category name stored in the table just skip that insert, to avoid these kind of errors?

Comment: here is your answer, use upsert https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#upserts

Comment: Thanks! Using upsert it shows "message: "Too few arguments to function Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::upsert(), 1 passed in /var/www/html/app/Nova/Post.php on line 69 and at least 2 expected"
".

Comment: It seems that its because of the laravel version, the upsert doesn't seem available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many methods that accomplish what you want using `Query Builder`

### [insertOrIgnore](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#insert-statements)

Here is an example of this method:

```
$data = array_map(fn ($category) => [
    'post_id' => $postId,
    'category_id' => $category['id'],
    'category_name' => $category['name']['en_gb'],
], $postInformation['categories']['data']);

DB::table('post_categories')->insertOrIgnore($data);
```

### [upsert](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#upserts)

Here is an example of this method:

```
$data = array_map(fn ($category) => [
    'post_id' => $postId,
    'category_id' => $category['id'],
    'category_name' => $category['name']['en_gb'],
], $postInformation['categories']['data']);

DB::table('post_categories')->upsert($data, ['the_column_must_be_unique'], ['the_columns_you_want_update_here']);
```

### [updateOrInsert](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#update-or-insert)

Here is an example of this method:

```
$data = array_map(fn ($category) => [
    'post_id' => $postId,
    'category_id' => $category['id'],
    'category_name' => $category['name']['en_gb'],
], $postInformation['categories']['data']);

DB::table('post_categories')->updateOrInsert($data, ['the_columns_you_want_update_here' => $postId]);
```

There are many methods also that accomplish what you want using `Eloquent` and you'll find many examples in this [section](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#retrieving-or-creating-models)

Comment: Thanks! It works. However, although it stores on the db the values when the page is refreshed it also shows this message {message: "Undefined array key "id"", exception: "ErrorException",…}
exception: "ErrorException"
file: "/var/www/html/app/Nova/Post.php"
line: 59
message: "Undefined array key \"id\""
trace: [{,…}, {file: "/var/www/html/app/Nova/Postl.php", line: 59,…},…]. Do you know what can be the issue? Thanks!

Comment: Make sure that `$category` is an array and has the `id` key

Comment: you mean the $category that is passed to the array_map function?

Comment: yup because I don't see `id` else

Comment: The id is in the $postInformation, the dd($postInformation);) shows:

^ array:38 [
  "id" => 5
  .....
  "categories" => array:2 [
    "data" => array:15 [
      0 => array:3 [
        "id" => 6
        "name" => array:1 [
          "en" => "General"
        ]
        "on_request" => 0
      ]
      1 => array:3 [
        "id" => 14
        "name" => array:1 [
          "en" => "Tuts"
        ]
        "on_request" => 0
      ]
  ]
 
    ....
  ]
]

Comment: try `$category[0]['id']` because this array of arraies

Comment: Like that shows "{message: "Undefined array key 0", exception: "ErrorException",…}
exception: "ErrorException"
file: "/var/www/html/app/Nova/Post.php"
line: 59
message: "Undefined array key 0""

Comment: It seems really strange for example " $postInformation = (new postInformation)->handle(['field' => 'slug', 'value' => $this->slug]);
        $postId =  $postInformation['id'];" dd($postInformation) shows the correct id without errors but then the $postId used inside the array_map it seems that don't work properly.

Comment: It seems that works with data_get($postInformation, 'id'). But now it shows {message: "array_map(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type array, null given",…}
exception: "TypeError"
file: "/var/www/html/app/Nova/Post.php"
line: 69
message: "array_map(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type array, null given". Do you know what can be the issue? Thanks